# Difference between global/local variables in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

```
test=4
def sum1(var):
    print("in function, test",test) 
    var+=1
    test=7
    print("in function, var",var)
    print("in function, test",test)  
sum1(5)
print(test)
```

I'm trying to understand global and local variable, so I try it this way: a global and a local variable that has same names (I know we normally don't do that).

In this program it has an "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test' referenced before assignment"
I am wondering why the first print() that prints the test cannot be printed out? Why wouldn't it call the global "test"?

Comment: [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) (in the Tutorial)
[4.2. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) (in the language reference)

Comment: The assignment `test=7` **in** the function makes `test` local to the function and the interpreter knows that the assignment happens after the print so it is complaining. The interpreter knows this because it has already done some *processing* of `sum1` - it has made a function object of it and the assignment causes an *entry* in its locals dictionary but it doesn't have anything assigned to it yet. If you comment out `test=7` it should run.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers in that duplicate other than the accepted one. It would be worthwhile reading some of those also.

Comment: I misspoke, `test` is not in the locals dictionary until the assignment but the *function* knows about it; add `print(sum1.__code__.co_varnames)` as the first statement in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because your local `test` shadows the name of the global `test`, it's unclear to which one you're referring. If you comment out the line `test = 7` in your function, you won't get the error, as python assumes you're referring to the global `test`.

If you insist on using var names in your local scope that shadow global vars (and you've just discovered why that's a very bad idea), you can be explicit about it:

```
def sum1(var):
    global test
    print("in function, test", test)
    ...
```

Now, however, when you get to `test = 7`, you're modifying the global `test` var. That's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: `global test` isn't "be[ing] explicit about" "using var names in your local scope that shadow global vars"; it's just using the global variable.  Actually reaching around a local would require something like `globals()["var"]`.